# Initialize the interior edge index of customized edge class

Tags: boost, graph

I am farily new to the BGL(boost graph library). As I am trying to use the planar map traversal, I encounter following problem of compiling, can anyone kindly explain to me what I did wrong? The code causing the error is:

```
put(e_index, *ei, edge_count++);

planar_face_traversal(g, &embedding[0], v_vis);

planar_face_traversal(g, &embedding[0], e_vis);


/usr/include/boost/property_map/property_map.hpp:361: error: no match for 'operator=' in '(&((const boost::adj_list_edge_property_map<boost::undirected_tag, boost::detail::error_property_not_found, boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, long unsigned int, boost::property<boost::edge_bundle_t, Edge, boost::no_property>, boost::edge_index_t>&)pa))->boost::adj_list_edge_property_map<Directed, Value, Ref, Vertex, Property, Tag>::operator[] [with Directed = boost::undirected_tag, Value = boost::detail::error_property_not_found, Ref = boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, Vertex = long unsigned int, Property = boost::property<boost::edge_bundle_t, Edge, boost::no_property>, Tag = boost::edge_index_t, boost::adj_list_edge_property_map<Directed, Value, Ref, Vertex, Property, Tag>::key_type = boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::undirected_tag, long unsigned int>](k) = v'

/usr/include/boost/property_map/property_map.hpp:391: error: no match for 'operator+' in '((const boost::iterator_property_map<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::map<long unsigned int, boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::undirected_tag, long unsigned int>, std::less<long unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const long unsigned int, boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::undirected_tag, long unsigned int> > > >*, std::vector<std::map<long unsigned int, boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::undirected_tag, long unsigned int>, std::less<long unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const long unsigned int, boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::undirected_tag, long unsigned int> > > >, std::allocator<std::map<long unsigned int, boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::undirected_tag, long unsigned int>, std::less<long unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const long unsigned int, boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::undirected_tag, long unsigned int> > > > > > >, boost::adj_list_edge_property_map<boost::undirected_tag, boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, long unsigned int, const boost::property<boost::edge_bundle_t, Edge, boost::no_property>, boost::edge_index_t>, std::map<long unsigned int, boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::undirected_tag, long unsigned int>, std::less<long unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const long unsigned int, boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::undirected_tag, long unsigned int> > > >, std::map<long unsigned int, boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::undirected_tag, long unsigned int>, std::less<long unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const long unsigned int, boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::undirected_tag, long unsigned int> > > >&>*)this)->boost::iterator_property_map<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::map<long unsigned int, boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::undirected_tag, long unsigned int>, std::less<long unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const long unsigned int, boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::undirected_tag, long unsigned int> > > >*, std::vector<std::map<long unsigned int, boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::undirected_tag, long unsigned int>, std::less<long unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const long unsigned int, boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::undirected_tag, long unsigned int> > > >, std::allocator<std::map<long unsigned int, boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::undirected_tag, long unsigned int>, std::less<long unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const long unsigned int, boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::undirected_tag, long unsigned int> > > > > > >, boost::adj_list_edge_property_map<boost::undirected_tag, boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, long unsigned int, const boost::property<boost::edge_bundle_t, Edge, boost::no_property>, boost::edge_index_t>, std::map<long unsigned int, boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::undirected_tag, long unsigned int>, std::less<long unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const long unsigned int, boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::undirected_tag, long unsigned int> > > >, std::map<long unsigned int, boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::undirected_tag, long unsigned int>, std::less<long unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const long unsigned int, boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::undirected_tag, long unsigned int> > > >&>::iter + boost::get [with PropertyMap = boost::adj_list_edge_property_map<boost::undirected_tag, boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, long unsigned int, const boost::property<boost::edge_bundle_t, Edge, boost::no_property>, boost::edge_index_t>, Reference = const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, K = boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::undirected_tag, long unsigned int>]((*(const boost::put_get_helper<const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::adj_list_edge_property_map<boost::undirected_tag, boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, long unsigned int, const boost::property<boost::edge_bundle_t, Edge, boost::no_property>, boost::edge_index_t> >*)(&((const boost::iterator_property_map<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::map<long unsigned int, boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::undirected_tag, long unsigned int>, std::less<long unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const long unsigned int, boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::undirected_tag, long unsigned int> > > >*, std::vector<std::map<long unsigned int, boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::undirected_tag, long unsigned int>, std::less<long unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const long unsigned int, boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::undirected_tag, long unsigned int> > > >, std::allocator<std::map<long unsigned int, boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::undirected_tag, long unsigned int>, std::less<long unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const long unsigned int, boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::undirected_tag, long unsigned int> > > > > > >, boost::adj_list_edge_property_map<boost::undirected_tag, boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, long unsigned int, const boost::property<boost::edge_bundle_t, Edge, boost::no_property>, boost::edge_index_t>, std::map<long unsigned int, boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::undirected_tag, long unsigned int>, std::less<long unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const long unsigned int, boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::undirected_tag, long unsigned int> > > >, std::map<long unsigned int, boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::undirected_tag, long unsigned int>, std::less<long unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const long unsigned int, boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::undirected_tag, long unsigned int> > > >&>*)this)->boost::iterator_property_map<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::map<long unsigned int, boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::undirected_tag, long unsigned int>, std::less<long unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const long unsigned int, boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::undirected_tag, long unsigned int> > > >*, std::vector<std::map<long unsigned int, boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::undirected_tag, long unsigned int>, std::less<long unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const long unsigned int, boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::undirected_tag, long unsigned int> > > >, std::allocator<std::map<long unsigned int, boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::undirected_tag, long unsigned int>, std::less<long unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const long unsigned int, boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::undirected_tag, long unsigned int> > > > > > >, boost::adj_list_edge_property_map<boost::undirected_tag, boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, long unsigned int, const boost::property<boost::edge_bundle_t, Edge, boost::no_property>, boost::edge_index_t>, std::map<long unsigned int, boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::undirected_tag, long unsigned int>, std::less<long unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const long unsigned int, boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::undirected_tag, long unsigned int> > > >, std::map<long unsigned int, boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::undirected_tag, long unsigned int>, std::less<long unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const long unsigned int, boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::undirected_tag, long unsigned int> > > >&>::index)), (*(const boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::undirected_tag, long unsigned int>*)(& v)))'

#include <iostream>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/properties.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_traits.hpp>
#include <boost/property_map/property_map.hpp>
#include <boost/ref.hpp>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/graph/planar_face_traversal.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/boyer_myrvold_planar_test.hpp> using namespace boost;



// Some planar face traversal visitors that will // print the vertices and edges on the faces

class Vertex{ public:
    int i;//just some variable
    Vertex(){}
    Vertex(int val){
        i = val;
    } };

class Edge{ public:
    int i;//just some variable
    Edge(){}
    Edge(int val){
        i = val;
    } };

struct output_visitor : public planar_face_traversal_visitor {   void begin_face() { std::cout << "New face: "; }   void end_face() { std::cout << std::endl; } };



struct vertex_output_visitor : public output_visitor {   void next_vertex(Vertex v)   {
    std::cout << v.i << " ";   } };

struct edge_output_visitor : public output_visitor {   void next_edge(Edge e)   {
    std::cout << e.i << " ";   } };

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  typedef adjacency_list
    < vecS,
      vecS,
      undirectedS,
      Vertex,
      Edge
    >
    graph;

  // Create a graph - this is a biconnected, 3 x 3 grid.   // It should have four small (four vertex/four edge) faces and   // one large face that contains all but the interior vertex   graph g;


  typedef boost::graph_traits<graph>::vertex_descriptor VertexDescriptor;   typedef boost::graph_traits<graph>::edge_descriptor EdgeDescriptor;

  VertexDescriptor v0 = add_vertex(g);   VertexDescriptor v1 = add_vertex(g);   VertexDescriptor v2 = add_vertex(g);   VertexDescriptor v3 = add_vertex(g);   VertexDescriptor v4 = add_vertex(g);   add_edge(v0,v1,g);   add_edge(v1,v2,g);   add_edge(v2,v3,g);   add_edge(v3,v4,g);   add_edge(v4,v0,g);

  add_edge(v0,v2,g);   add_edge(v0,v3,g);

  add_edge(v1,v4,g);   add_edge(v1,v3,g);

  add_edge(v2, v4, g);

  // Initialize the interior edge index   property_map<graph, edge_index_t>::type e_index = get(edge_index, g);


  graph_traits<graph>::edges_size_type edge_count = 0;   graph_traits<graph>::edge_iterator ei, ei_end;   for(boost::tie(ei, ei_end) = edges(g); ei != ei_end; ++ei)   {
      put(e_index, *ei, edge_count++);
      std::cout << *ei << std::endl;   }

  // Test for planarity - we know it is planar, we just want to   // compute the planar embedding as a side-effect


  typedef std::vector< graph_traits<graph>::edge_descriptor > vec_t;   std::vector<vec_t> embedding(num_vertices(g));   std::cout <<  num_vertices(g) << std::endl;   if (boyer_myrvold_planarity_test(boyer_myrvold_params::graph = g,
                                   boyer_myrvold_params::embedding =
                                       &embedding[0]
                                   )
      )
    std::cout << "Input graph is planar" << std::endl;   else
    std::cout << "Input graph is not planar" << std::endl;


  std::cout << std::endl << "Vertices on the faces: " << std::endl;   vertex_output_visitor v_vis;   planar_face_traversal(g, &embedding[0], v_vis);

  std::cout << std::endl << "Edges on the faces: " << std::endl;   output_visitor e_vis;   planar_face_traversal(g, &embedding[0], e_vis);

  return 0; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has several problems. The one that causes your compiler error is that your graph does not have an internal `edge_index` property and you are trying to use that. It can easily be solved changing your `EdgeProperty` to `property<edge_index_t,std::size_t,Edge>`. There are also problems with your `xxx_output_visitors`. `next_vertex` and `next_edge` expect a vertex_descriptor and an edge_descriptor respectively. I have changed them below to do something "useful". The last problem is that `boyer_myrvold_planarity_test` returns false for your graph. Since I really don't know a thing about the problem domain I have simply have changed your graph with the one found [here](http://www.boost.org/libs/graph/doc/boyer_myrvold.html).

**Update:** If you want to avoid using `property<edge_index_t,std::size_t,Edge>` you can simply create an external property map and then pass it to `planar_face_traversal`. `boyer_myrvold_planarity_test` does not need to be passed the edge index map unless you also use the parameter `kuratowski_subgraph`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/properties.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_traits.hpp>
#include <boost/property_map/property_map.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/iteration_macros.hpp>
#include <boost/ref.hpp>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/graph/planar_face_traversal.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/boyer_myrvold_planar_test.hpp> 

using namespace boost;



// Some planar face traversal visitors that will 
// print the vertices and edges on the faces

class Vertex
{ 
   public:
    int i;//just some variable
    Vertex(){}
    Vertex(int val){
        i = val;
    } 
};

class Edge
{ 
   public:
    int i;//just some variable
    Edge(){}
    Edge(int val){
        i = val;
    } 
};


typedef adjacency_list
    < vecS,
      vecS,
      undirectedS,
      Vertex,
      Edge
    >
    graph_type;

struct output_visitor : public planar_face_traversal_visitor 
{   
   void begin_face() { std::cout << "New face: "; }   
   void end_face() { std::cout << std::endl; } 
};



struct vertex_output_visitor : public output_visitor 
{   
   vertex_output_visitor(const graph_type& g_):g(g_){}
   template <typename VertexDesc>
   void next_vertex(VertexDesc v)  
   {
      //std::cout << g[v].i << " "; //This would do what you wanted if you initialize "i"
      std::cout << get(vertex_index,g,v) << " ";   
   } 

   const graph_type& g;
};

struct edge_output_visitor : public output_visitor 
{   
   edge_output_visitor(const graph_type& g_):g(g_){}
   template <typename EdgeDesc>
   void next_edge(EdgeDesc e)   
   {
      //std::cout << g[e].i << " "; //This would do what you wanted
      std::cout << source(e,g) << "-" << target(e,g) << " ";   
   } 

   const graph_type& g;
};

int main() {



  // Create a graph - this is a biconnected, 3 x 3 grid.   
  // It should have four small (four vertex/four edge) faces and   
  // one large face that contains all but the interior vertex   
  graph_type g;


  typedef boost::graph_traits<graph_type>::vertex_descriptor VertexDescriptor;   
  typedef boost::graph_traits<graph_type>::edge_descriptor EdgeDescriptor;

  VertexDescriptor A = add_vertex(g);   
  VertexDescriptor B = add_vertex(g);   
  VertexDescriptor C = add_vertex(g);   
  VertexDescriptor D = add_vertex(g);   
  VertexDescriptor E = add_vertex(g);   
  add_edge(A,B,g);   
  add_edge(A,C,g);   
  add_edge(A,D,g);   
  add_edge(A,E,g);   
  add_edge(B,D,g);   
  add_edge(B,E,g);
  add_edge(C,D,g);   
  add_edge(C,E,g);   
  add_edge(D,E,g);   


  typedef std::map<EdgeDescriptor, size_t> EdgeIndexMap;
  EdgeIndexMap mapIndex;
  boost::associative_property_map<EdgeIndexMap> my_edge_index_map(mapIndex);
  graph_traits<graph_type>::edges_size_type current_index=0;
  BGL_FORALL_EDGES(e,g,graph_type)
  {
      put(my_edge_index_map,e,current_index++);
      std::cout << e << std::endl;
  }

  // Test for planarity - we know it is planar, we just want to   
  // compute the planar embedding as a side-effect


  typedef std::vector< graph_traits<graph_type>::edge_descriptor > vec_t;   
  std::vector<vec_t> embedding(num_vertices(g));   
  std::cout <<  num_vertices(g) << std::endl; 

  //if you use the parameter "kuratowski_subgraph" you'll need to pass also my_edge_index_map
  if (boyer_myrvold_planarity_test(boyer_myrvold_params::graph = g,
                                   boyer_myrvold_params::embedding =
                                       &embedding[0]
                                   )
      )
    std::cout << "Input graph is planar" << std::endl;   
  else
    std::cout << "Input graph is not planar" << std::endl;


  std::cout << std::endl << "Vertices on the faces: " << std::endl;   
  vertex_output_visitor v_vis(g);   
  planar_face_traversal(g, &embedding[0], v_vis, my_edge_index_map);

  std::cout << std::endl << "Edges on the faces: " << std::endl;   
  edge_output_visitor e_vis(g);   
  planar_face_traversal(g, &embedding[0], e_vis, my_edge_index_map);

  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Your code is working! However, I'm looking for a solution that uses bundle property, basically avoiding       property<edge_index_t, std::size_t,Edge>, and just use Edge. Is there a way to do that?